# Add a hyperlink to grid column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'd like to have a link on the FileName column, so users can click and open a PDF file (no download, only open to view). This is what I have tried, but I don't know how to pass the file name to the server function.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.FileName)
       .ClientTemplate( "<a href='" + FileHelper.GetFullPath({how to pass the file name here}) + ">/#= FileName #</a>")
```

The `FileHelper.GetFullPath` method is a server function to generate the full path for the file. The full path should be:

> http://servername/applicationname/filefolders/filename.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't implement the PDF download on the client-side easily. You should instead stream the PDF file using another action method.

Try this instead:

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("GetPdf", "Home") + "?fileName=#= FileName #'>#=FileName#</a>");

public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
{
    string path = FileHelper.GetFullPath(fileName);
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf", fileName + ".pdf");
}
```

Comment: I tried the javascript version and it did not work.  No link is shown.  I will take a look again later.

Comment: @CoolDev Please have a look at my updated answer and see if it works for you.